# I want to Print my output on pop up window? how should I approach?

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter, popupwindow

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime 

def write_slogan():
    dt_object = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    print("OrderName: %s"%dt_object)


master = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(master, 
          text='ORDER Number', 
          command=write_slogan).grid(row=3, 
                                    column=1, 
                                    sticky=tk.W, 
                                    pady=4)

tk.mainloop()
```

How should I print the above code outputs on the pop-up window rather than terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Print message inside tkinter window rather than terminal**

If you just want to print the message in the `root` window, you can use a `label` widget like this in the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

def write_slogan():
    info_message = "Your message"
    tk.Label(master, text=info_message).grid(row=2, column=1) 

btn = tk.Button(master, text='ORDER Number', command=write_slogan)
btn.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)

master.mainloop()
```

[image: output]

**Print message in a separate pop-up window**

You can use a message box from the tkinter `messagebox` module to pop up some info with your info message displayed in it.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmb

def write_slogan():
    info_message = "Your message"
    # info message box
    tkmb.showinfo("Output", info_message)

master = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(master, text='ORDER Number', command=write_slogan)
btn.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)

master.mainloop()
```

[image: output]

**Creating a toplevel window as a pop up window**

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmb

def write_slogan():
    # toplevel window
    top_win = tk.Toplevel(master)
    top_win.title('Toplevel')
    info_message = "Your message"
    # info message box
    tk.Label(top_win, text=info_message).grid(row=0, column=0) 

master = tk.Tk()
master.title('Master')

btn = tk.Button(master, text='ORDER Number', command=write_slogan)
btn.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)

master.mainloop()
```

[image: output]

Comment: Hey! Thank you. Is there a way to save my previous result and print the new one?  like u said 'your message' and it prints ' your message' in your first step, now I want to save 'mango' and 'your message'. my basic idea is that I created a list of fruits and I want to show it on the screen.

Comment: I have written another answer that will save the previous result and print the new one.

Answer (score 1):

So if you have a list of messages (fruits) to print, you can use the following method to save  previous result and print the new one

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

# list of fruits
fruits = ['Mango', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', ]

#action to be performed when button clicked
def clicked():
    for ind, fruit in enumerate(fruits):
        # print names in the tkinter window
        # create a label widget
        names_label = tk.Label(window)
        # give it a position using grid
        names_label.grid(row=int(ind)+1, column=0)
        # print the fruit name in the label
        names_label.config(text=fruit)

btn = tk.Button(window, text="Print fruits", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=30, pady=2)

window.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

[image: gui window]

> Click on `Print fruits` button to print all the fruit names

[image: gui window 2]

The important thing to understand here is the `for` loop is used to create as many `Label` widgets equal to the number of elements in the list and the list item `index` is used for giving `row` and `column` positions to these label widgets.

**Printing the names in a toplevel window**

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

# list of fruits
fruits = ['Mango', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', ]

#action to be performed when button clicked
def clicked():
    # create a toplevel
    top_window = tk.Toplevel(window)
    for ind, fruit in enumerate(fruits):
        # print names in the tkinter window
        # create a label widget in top_window
        names_label = tk.Label(top_window)
        # give it a position using grid
        names_label.grid(row=int(ind)+1, column=0)
        # print the fruit name in the label
        names_label.config(text=fruit)

btn = tk.Button(window, text="Print fruits", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=30, pady=2)

window.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

[image: toplevel gui]